# Display only the right side of long Text in JTable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, render

is there any posibility  to display only the right side of an long text in a JTable?
eg i have this long string:

```
asldjklasjdklasjdklasjdlkasjkldjaslkjdklasjdklasjdlkajskldjaslk
```

in my table is displayed:

```
asldjklasjdklas...
```

but i want

```
...jdlkajskldjaslk
```

to just make the column right aligned did not work :(

Comment: I provide the code for your solution, and show you how to add the LeftDotRenderer to your table and you don't even give me an upvote or accept my answer. Well I guess I won't be helping you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your own [TableCellRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) implementation:

```
class MyTableCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
    ...
}
```

and replace the [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) default renderer with it:

```
jTable.setDefaultRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
```

or, if you want to set it for just some column, say, the first:

```
jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer())
```

[Left Dot Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/12/left-dot-renderer/), previously mentioned by @camickr, is a [TableCellRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) implementation.

Comment: ok, so i have done this: i have my own JTable, and added this to the constructor: this.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new LeftDotRenderer()); but this didnt work :(
the leftdotrenderer is not even called once, when im doing some sysout stuff in it, i never see any output

Comment: ah ok... @adrianboimvaser works, my problem was that i had to use the type of my own jtable implementation also in the renderer...

Comment: @reox. all this poster did was reference the code I posted in my answer.

Comment: I wrote more than half of my answer before yours. I gave you credit. Also, my answer is still useful in the event that LeftDotRenderer webpage ceases to exist.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [Left Dot Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/12/left-dot-renderer/).